# Make an URl Private unless redirected by window.location.href

Tags: javascript, html, url, private

I'm currently working on a car-parking game. I want it to be special so everytime you pass a level you get a point - but if the user goes to that page with, let's say: 10 pts, how do you make the page private unless redirected by the code? (P.S. I want JavaScript, & HTML Included)

Comment: You can check the Referer, but this can be spoofed. You should be keeping track of the score on the server.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: The game code on the server should determine when you pass a level.

Comment: Ok, let me do some research and try it out. I'll reply if it works soon.